# Pandas to_datetime does not ignore already converted dates

Tags: python, pandas

So my timestamp column has a mixture of both epoch(s) and milliseconds(ms) times. Setting `pd.to_datetime(unit='s', errors='ignore')` first gives this as the [head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ff0zS.png) and this as the tail [tail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0yP0.png) as I thought it would. It ignored the 'ms' type timestamp.

But when I run `df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms', errors='ignore')` my [head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZgoT.png) becomes NaT but my [tail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KolNC.png) correctly converts. Why is the function not ignoring the already converted timestamps?

Why is this? Is there a way around converting both unit types using an inbuilt? My current solution iterates over each row to check if the length of of the time stamp is greater than 10, if it is cut it down to 10. After which I use to_datetime.

My data set is to large for the current solution as it takes way to long.

**EDIT**

Timestamp column would look something like this

1541760294

1541746328

1541723516

1543826478000

1543804455000

1541741097

Comment: Welcome to SO. Better to use text than images in your question.

Comment: Just wanted to make my problem clear. Will do next time

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick hack, but you could just use the index given by a type check to convert the indexes you did not get in the first pass:

```
idx = [df['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: type(x)!=datetime.datetime)]

df['timestamp'][idx] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms', errors='ignore')
```

I am not entirely sure what the datatype would be but I am guessing it would be a datetime.datetime...

Comment: Yeah, you probably need to set a different type "datetime.datetime", If you include a dummy data set in your question, we would be able to run the code and answer the question much easier

Comment: Edited my post to include a dummy timestamp column